# Font anti-aliasing issues with jQuery.fadeIn in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm banging my head against the wall with an issue I'm having in IE8. I am using the fadeIn function on jQuery to make the site content fade in. This works perfectly fine in all of the other browsers, but when the fadeIn finishes in IE8 the font anti-aliasing seems to change, causing the text to shift slightly.

You can see the site at http://www.ipulse.biz. The code I'm using to cause the fade in is quite simple, as shown below.

```
var showContent = function() {

  $('#content div:first').fadeIn(1000);

  $('#navigation').fadeIn(500);

} // end showContent
```

The code is called by a setInterval function, if that makes any difference.

Comment: That's real classy that you used the answers on your site, but didn't accept an answer here.  Come on, give back to the community for a few seconds.

Answer (score 17):

As previously explained, this is caused by Cleartype in Internet Explorer- but there is a workaround that will at least make this issue tolerable.

```
$('#navigation').fadeIn(500, function(){
    if ($.browser.msie){this.style.removeAttribute('filter');}
});
```

That should force IE to clear the transparency and thus render the text normally.

It still isn't pretty, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by ClearType disappearing in Internet Explorer, which is quite annoying.

http://blog.bmn.name/2008/03/jquery-fadeinfadeout-ie-cleartype-glitch/

Comment: this isn't limited to the jquery plugin. any time opacity is used in IE, the fonts lose their anti-aliasing in the translucent section

Comment: Yep, that's correct. However, since Philip is clearly using JQuery, I felt that a link with a solution to it, in JQuery, was good.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this solution and it doesn't seem to work. In fact, it causes the issue to happen in IE7 in addition to IE8 (which didn't happen before).

Comment: This works but unfortunately there's some slight shifting of the text when the filter is removed (using 'fadeTo' rather than 'fadeIn'). I'm guessing this is unavoidable though.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer comes a bit too late, but how about thinkin' vice-versa?
IE7 / IE8 don't keep anti-alias for Faded text, so, if you have a single color background (e.g. black), you can create an empty div, background-color: #000; position: absolute; display:block; and put it over the text element.

If your request is to have a text FadeIn effect you just have to apply the FadeOut to the "black" layer over it, and vice-versa.

This way the text anti-alias is kept intact.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the very late reply, but I had the same problem and was searching for a solution when I came across this topic. I didn't find a working solution in this topic, but I came up with a simple solution that seems to fix the problem perfectly.

In stead of using:

$('.element').fadeIn(500)

use fadeTo and fade to 99%:

$('.element').fadeTo(500, 0.99)

You won't see a difference in the 1% and because it doesn't reach 100% opacity, IE doesn't seem to apply cleartype.

Let me know if this works for anyone else.

Comment: Interesting but completely the opposite of what the original question was asking for. Need to apply cleartype, not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be called after the fade effect is completed (e.g. 500ms after etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding in the css for the required text

filter:alpha(opacity=99);

this will only effect ie. I still get a small shift in ie7 but it's exceptable.

You can see it working here http://thriive.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

Found a ready solution for that problem.

http://jquery.malsup.com/fadetest.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution: Create another DIV on your DOM as an overlay, and execute your fade functions on this DIV only. It will appear as though the content is fading in / out. This approach is also more performant, as you are only fading a single DIV instead of multiple elements. Here is an example:

```
$('#containeroverlay').width($('#container').width()).height($('#container').height()).fadeIn('normal', function() {
    // Step 1: change your content underneath the hidden div
    // Step 2: hide the overlay
    $('#containeroverlay').fadeOut('normal');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with transparent PNG's in faded area's, but combining the above JS for removing the filter attribute with a tiny bit of css the image black 'border' was gone while fading.

Is my case it was a element that uses a css-sprite, so i only had to add this to my sprite class in the css:

```
.sprite{
    background-image: url('/images/sprite.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#00FFFFFF,startColorStr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00FFFFFF',startColorStr='#00FFFFFF');   /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using JQuery but I half-solved this issue by using the following CSS:

```
div
{
    opacity: .15;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=15)";
}
div:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:"";
}
```

The fully opaque text is anti-aliased now, but the translucent isn't. It's not a huge issue for the translucent text though.